# Where does SQL Server Agent save jobs?

Tags: sql, sql-server, restore, sql-server-agent

My server is down and I can only get the harddisk from it. I found my database and copied it but where I can find agent jobs? Where are they saved?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Jobs are stored in the [`msdb` database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187112.aspx).  You will have to restore this.

Comment: Lehnerwhen I just replace files for this db any settings can change?

Comment: If you are bringing this stuff up on a new server, I would probably restore MSDB to a new database ("MSDB_restore") and then [script the jobs](http://serverfault.com/a/14514) out of that to the new one.

Answer (score 20):

Within the MSDB database, jobs are stored in a tables called dbo.sysjobs. This joins to a table called dbo.sysjobsteps that stores details of the individule steps. The schedules are stored in dbo.sysjobschedules and the History is stored in dbo.sysjobhistory.

MSDB will also contain other instance level objects such as alerts, operators and SSIS packages.

Answer (score 4):

Let me present the following brilliant [SQL query](https://serverfault.com/questions/14524/get-a-list-of-sql-server-agent-jobs/53103#53103) to show us where & how SQL Server stores SQL Jobs.

```sql
-- List of all the SQL Jobs on a server with steps
SELECT
     job.job_id,
     notify_level_email,
     name,
     enabled,
     description,
     step_name,
     command,
     server,
     database_name
FROM
    msdb.dbo.sysjobs job
INNER JOIN 
    msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps steps        
ON
    job.job_id = steps.job_id
WHERE 1=1
    --AND job.enabled = 1 -- uncomment this to see enabled SQL Jobs
```

Also I remove "msdb." prefixes inside the query to see SQL Jobs from a msdb database restored from a backup.